# Index on array of objects param

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I want to do a index in to 'Text' param of object inside the array because im doing a searchbar and will look in 'title' and 'tags' fields of model

```
const needSchema = new Schema({
    owner: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: User
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tags: {
        type: [Object],
        required: false
    },
}, {
        timestamps: {
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at'
        }
    });
needSchema.index({ title: 'text', 'tags.text': 'text' });

const Need = mongoose.model('Need', needSchema);
```

Actually only title is working. I cant get results for tag array of objects.
Tag array:

```
tag:[
   {'id':'text1', 'text':'text1',
   {....},
]

What is wrong?
```

Comment: Is it the `tag` array or the `tags` array. The schema and the index creation statement in mongoose both say `tags` but your snippet at the end of the question says `tag`. If the documents in the collection actually have `tag` that would explain a lot. As would if you originally set the index with `title` **only** and then later added the other field. Unfortunately this did not do things correctly, because mongoose cannot handle changes like that. You can drop all indexes on the collection and restart your application which should then correctly index it.

Comment: that 'tag' was a typo when i was posting this question. Documents are 'Tags'

Comment: Well the same things in the rest of the comment apply. I suggest dropping all indexes on the collection and starting the application again, or defining the text index on both fields manually. Point being that the index you expect to be there likely is not actually there.

Comment: After dropping indexes, now is working fine. Thanks